# Python code to cancel a running Oracle SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, oracle, kill, cancellation

I have the following python code which runs multiple SQL Queries in Oracle database and combines them into one dataframe.

The queries exist in a txt file and every row is a separate SQL query. The loop runs sequentially the queries. I want to cancel any SQL queries that run for more than 10 secs so as not to create an overhead in the database. 
The following code doesnt actually me give the results that i want. More specifically this bit of the code really help me on my issue:

```
        if (time.time() - start) > 10: 
        connection.cancel()
```

Full python code is the following. Probably it is an oracle function that can be called so as to cancel the query.

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import time

ip = 'XX.XX.XX.XX'
port = XXXX
svc  = 'XXXXXX'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name = svc)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='XXXXXX'
                           , password='XXXXXX'
                           , dsn=dsn_tns
                           , encoding = "UTF-8"   
                           , nencoding = "UTF-8"  
                           )

filepath = 'C:/XXXXX'

appended_data = []

with open(filepath + 'sql_queries.txt') as fp:  
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        start = time.time()
        df = pd.read_sql(line, con=connection)
        if (time.time() - start) > 10: 
            connection.cancel()
            print("Cancel")         
        appended_data.append(df)
        df_combined = pd.concat(appended_data, axis=0)
        line = fp.readline()
        print(time.time() - start)
    fp.close()
```

Comment: As far as I see, connection.cancel() is the only viable option

Comment: @HellHammer I have used connection.cancel() but the query is first sent to the database and then the statement connection.cancel() runs. In other words the queries always run no matter what. I want the code to capture the execution time and then kill the query

Comment: You need the query to execute async for any timer on the execution time to work. Cancelling the client side issue of the query does not mean the DB will actually cancel - you would have to go specifically kill the spid in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to spend some time tuning the queries to make them as efficient as necessary. As @Andrew points out we can't easily kill a database query from outside the database - or even from another session inside the database (it requires DBA level privileges).

Indeed, most DBAs would rather you ran a query for 20 seconds rather than attempt to kill every query which runs more than 10. Apart from anything else, having a process which polls you query to see how long it's been running for is itself a waste of database resources.

I suggest you discuss this with your DBA. You may find you're worrying about nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The queries are tuned. It is just the nature of the task that makes it difficult. Indeed it is very difficult to kill a query outside the database. Maybe it is best to look at a different approach

Comment: You could look at using the resource manager to kill off sessions when they exceed a certain threshold --> https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9538186000346830893

Answer (score 0):

Look at cx_Oracle 7's [Connection.callTimeout](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#Connection.callTimeout) setting.  You'll need to be using Oracle client libraries 18+.  (These will connect to Oracle DB 11.2+).  The [doc for the equivalent node-oracledb parameter](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#dbcalltimeouts) explains the fine print behind the Oracle behavior and round trips.